# Load balancing since Node v0.12.2 - cluster, pm2 or nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, load-balancing, haproxy, pm2

With Node v0.12.2, the cluster module [supports Round-Robin (RR) load balancing](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/whats-new-in-node-js-v0-12-cluster-round-robin-load-balancing/), which ensures load is more evenly distributed than the previous OS-level load balancing.

So now we are spoilt for choice:

1. Use the [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module
2. Use [`pm2`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) which uses the cluster module under the hood
3. Use [`nginx`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)
4. Use [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)

I am aware of this excellent [post](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/load-balancing-node-js/) as well as [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28106302/2317532) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24628150/2317532) here on SO, but none have addressed the newer Cluster module with RR mode. So the question boils down to:

Judging only on their load balancing capabilities, should I use `pm2` or `nginx`?

Comment: It would only be more even if each request was equal in resource needs.

Comment: @KevinB By 'It' you mean the Node Cluster? But does `nginx` not suffer the same issues? It has three different load balancing modes, none of which takes into account the 'resource needs' of each connection.

Comment: You could use both. You could also use HAProxy in front of pm2 by using the `fork_mode` instead of the `cluster`. The pm2 cluster is nothing else than the [node cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) under the hood.

Comment: @soyuka How can you use both `nginx` and cluster both for load balancing? From what I know, with `nginx` you have to specify different ports to different instances of the same application, whereas with cluster you have all the instances listening to the same socket but spawning different threads.

Comment: I'm saying use `nginx` and `pm2` in a `fork mode` for example.

Comment: @soyuka I'll read about that thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

> If it's just `pm2` vs. `nginx` go for nginx. **Better**: both. **Best**: a even broader setup.

If you want the most mature load balancing features use `HAProxy`. It's **do one thing best**. You'll get SSL-termination, ACLs and it being very lightweight. I can't prove with numbers, but I feel it has the lowest hit on http requests. A good read is [this](https://serversforhackers.com/load-balancing-with-haproxy).

If you also need to serve (at least some) static content your goto option is `nginx` for its superior capabilities in this field. Also of your list it's the only one to provide such a feature. Except for `node` itself, but doing it very poorly.

`pm2` feels very heavy-weight IMO and tends to break more often. It's capabilities of process load balancing are very good and secures uptime of your node process. It abstracts `cluster`.

`cluster` feels just 'being fixed' to a bare minimum. In the past and maybe still the **os-level** support lead to different behaviours on different platforms. For example, bias to single processes.

My current setup is:

- `HAProxy` for cluster wide loadbalancing, including balancing several instances of a process per machine
- CDN for static content (e.g. [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/))
- `pm2` for process load balancing

Comment: can we use pm2 cluster mode with haproxy?